# code conversion: Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a very useful code bit in matlab.
I am using this code bit to save files in different parts of my code, without overwrite existing ones.
Can someone please guide me how to translate this code to C/C++ ?

```
i=0;  
name= ['test_', int2str(i)];  
while exist(name)  
    i=i+1;  
    name= ['test_', int2str(i)];  
end  
save(name)
```

Comment: what does `while exist(name)` do in Matlab? It appears as though this condition never fails and so loops forever?

Comment: @PP. `exist` presumably does a `stat` and returns true if `stat` returned a successful code, and false otherwise.

Comment: Oh, so this is code to detect the next filename to use in a folder? Next question: what operating system do you want the code to work on?

Comment: @PP. Yes, indeed, although of course it's susceptible to race conditions (and absolutely not recommended for use with `/tmp` for that reason).

Comment: @PP exist checks if a file by this name exists in folder.  I am working with windows 7.

Comment: First, learn Matlab. Next, learn C++. Then, translate the code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ on Windows I'd use something like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string num2str ( T Number )
{
     std::stringstream ss;
     ss << Number;
     return ss.str();
}

inline bool if_exists (const std::string& name) {
    std::ifstream f(name.c_str());
    if (f.good()) {
        f.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        f.close();
        return false;
    }   
}

std::string get_next_file( void )
{
    int i=1;
    while (if_exists("test_" + num2str(i) ) )
      i++;

    return std::string("test_") + num2str(i);
}
```